# How to integrate $\frac{x^n}{1+x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate the function
$ \frac{x^n}{1+x} $
I tried to do it by parts but it was of no use.

I did it by taking x as $-\theta$ and did the series expansion.
I need a better method.

Comment: You can make life easier if you start with a change of variables $t=x+1$.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{1+x^n}~dx~=~\frac\pi n~\csc\bigg(k~\frac\pi n\bigg)~$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the substitution $t=x+1$. Then you will get a polynomial in $t$ plus $(-1)^n/t$

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is odd,
$$\frac{x^n+1}{x+1}- \frac{1}{x+1} = (x^{n-1}- x^{n-2}+\cdots+1)- \frac{1}{x+1}$$
If $n$ is even,
$$\frac{x(x^{n-1}+1)}{x+1}- \frac{x}{x+1}= x(x^{n-2}- x^{n-3}+\cdots+1)- \frac{x}{x+1}$$
Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Write $x^n$ as $(x^n\pm 1)\mp 1$ depending on $n$ being odd or even. By integrating you will get $\pm \log(x+1)$ plus the integral of a polynomial in $x$. For instance:

$$\int\frac{x^3}{1+x}\,dx = -\log(1+x)+\int\frac{x^3+1}{x+1}\,dx = \log(1+x)+\int(x^2-x+1)\,dx\\ =-\log(1+x)+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2}{2}+x, $$

$$\int\frac{x^4}{1+x}\,dx = \log(1+x)+\int\frac{x^4-1}{x+1}\,dx = \log(1+x)+\int(x^3-x^2+x-1)\,dx\\ =\log(1+x)+\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}-x. $$